# Why container constraints property ignore minimum width?

Tags: flutter

Container constraints minimum width is ignored by container when the container is inside row and I also tried with constraints box but is is also not working. It's a strange behavior in a flutter.

This is not working:

```
    @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Row(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                children: [
                   ConstrainedBox(
                      constraints: BoxConstraints(minWidth: 50,maxWidth: 250),
                      child: AppTextField(
                        topMargin: 0,
                        controller: TextEditingController(),
                        hideLable: true,
                        onChange: (v) {},
                        hintText: AppStrings.hSearch,
                      ),
                    ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
```

This one is working:

```
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              ConstrainedBox(
                constraints: BoxConstraints(minWidth: 50,maxWidth: 250),
                child: AppTextField(
                  topMargin: 0,
                  controller: TextEditingController(),
                  hideLable: true,
                  onChange: (v) {},
                  hintText: AppStrings.hSearch,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: This article might help: [Understanding constraints](https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/layout/constraints)

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I think that's better to use `Container` instead `ConstrainedBox`
and secondly if you want to determine width and height for container you can put `Container` inside `SizedBox` thirdly I think you should determine
Constant width for first container after return